# How to make submission function work in a web form that is created using Google Apps Script and embedded in a Google Site?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sites

I want to embed a web created using Google Apps Script to a Google Site.  However, data submission button in the form comes to be defunct, when the form is embedded in a Google Site like [this](https://sites.google.com/view/mwe4stackoverflow/).

In the web form, form visitors input data to the form produced by `index.html` and see `result.html` after data submission. There is an internal link in `index.html` to connect a header and its related contents. The form app successfully works when it is not embedded in any other site. See [the form app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzbFRqqGgCjOdY4MbXcFlIujLxk8r9UigauarN2bwKLjFA54LgWmkqIFy196FXT6Jxv4w/exec) and you will find  the data submission button works fine.

Does anybody tell me what I am missing?

## MWE

I have four files in the same project of Google Apps Script:

1. **`index.html`** that produces the form
2. **`JavaScript.html`** that defines functions used in `index.html`
3. **`result.html`** that is presented after the form submission
4. **`code.gs`** that shows the form by `doGet()`, and processes the submitted data and presents `result.html` by `doPost()`. `include()` defined in this file enables to input `JavaScript.html` into `index.html`

### `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!-- <?!= include("css"); ?> -->
  </head>

  <body onload="addOptions()">   <!--Execute addOptions function immediately after a page has been loaded-->
    <form class="" action="<?!= getScriptUrl(); ?>" method="post" onSubmit="document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;">
      <div>
        <h1 id="Question">
          Choose either cheesecake or chocolate cake.
        </h1>
          <select id="dropdownList" name="cake" class="form-control"> 
          </select>
      </div>
      <p>
        <div style="width:100px;height:500px;border:1px solid #000;">
          Blank box to scroll down
        </div>
      </p>
      <p>
        Please do not forget what you've answered in the <a href="#Question" target="_self">question<a>
      </p>
      <div class="form-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
  <?!= include('JavaScript') ?>
</html>
```

### `JavaScript.html`

```html
<script>
  function addOptions() {
    /*This will call server-side Apps Script function getAvailableExps and if it is successful, 
    it will pass the return value to function addListValues which will add options to the drop down menu*/
    google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .withSuccessHandler(addListValues)
      .getAvailableExps();
  }

  function addListValues(values) { 
    //Add options to drop down menu using the values of parameter 'values'.     
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = values[i][0];
      option.value = values[i][0];
      var select = document.getElementById("dropdownList");
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
  }

  function onFailure(err) {
    alert('Error: ' + err.message);
  }
</script>
```

### `result.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base />
    <title>Thank you for your order!</title>
    <!-- <?!= include('css'); ?> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Don't forget what you've ordered!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

### `code.gs`

```java
var sheetID = "............................................";
var inventory_sheet = "Inventory";

function doGet(){
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("key", "sample");
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function getScriptUrl() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  Logger.log(url);
  return url;
}

function doPost(e){
  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  if (p.getProperty("key") == "sample") {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
    var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sh.appendRow([String(e.parameters.cake)]);

    //update Inventory
    var inventory = ss.getSheetByName(inventory_sheet);
    var row = inventory.createTextFinder(e.parameters.cake).findNext().getRow();
    var range = inventory.getRange(row, 2);
    var data = range.getValue();
    range.setValue(parseInt(data - 1))

    p.deleteProperty("key");
  }

  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("result").evaluate(); 
  
}

function getAvailableExps(){
  var inventory = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheetByName(inventory_sheet);
  var data =  inventory.getRange(2, 1, 2, 2).getValues();
  var filtered = data.filter(arr =>  arr[1] > 0 || arr[1] != ''); //remove exp to array if quantity is 0 or empty
  return filtered;
}
```

Comment: In my experience, embedded frames in Google Sites can be a little problematic due to some additional layers of security automatically added by Google Sites. It works to an extent, however if the embedded page performs complex actions, I often run into issues like this.  Perhaps working purely with Apps Scripts Webapp would be the best approach to this.

Comment: @Gustavo, indeed. I agree to your opinion that the pure apps scripts are the best. However, I have some problems with the URL of the apps when conducting large-scale research using the form apps with crowdsourcing services in my country: the URLs including `script` or `exec` are recognised as malwares in the crowdsourcing services... Therefore, I want to publish my form apps with different URLs from the original `https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec`. That's why I tried to embed the form app in a Google Site.

Comment: @Carlos Luis Rivera Thank you for replying. Now, I could replicate your new issue. It seems that when the while page of Web Apps is embedded and the scrollbar is not shown, the internal link doesn't work. When the scrollbar of the frame is shown, the link works. I could resolve your 1st question. But, I cannot resolve your 2nd question soon. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. I have to study more. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I cannot resolve your 2nd question soon and I think that my this answer might confuse other users.

Comment: @Carlos Luis Rivera I would like to study more for understanding various situations. I would be grateful if you can forgive my very poor skill that I cannot resolve your 2nd question soon although I could resolve your 1st question. About your this question, I would like to propose separating your 1st and 2nd question. And, how about posting your 2nd question as a new question? I think that by this, it will help users think of the solution. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike san, I edited the post here so that you can explain how to enable the data submission button in the embedded apps script. I will make another post for the internal link problem someday. If you came up any solution for the internal links before I post the new question, comment here. Then I will make a new post immediately so that you can give the solution.

Comment: Thank you for replying. And also, I appreciate your concern. I think that the only reason that I cannot resolve your 2nd question soon is due to my poor skill. In this case, as an answerer, I thought that I have to deeply apologize for this. About this question, I confirmed your updated question including only your 1st question. In this case, I think that you can use my proposed script. When you post your 2nd question as a new question, I would like to continue to try to think of the solution. I would like to support you.

Comment: About `I edited the post here so that you can explain how to enable the data submission button in the embedded apps script.`, by adding the result tested the internal link, I reopened my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Tanaike san, I reviewed your edit in the post and upvoted and accepted it! I really appreciate your kind supports and brilliant solutions!

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your new question related to the internal link, I would like to try to think of the solution and/or workaround. Thank you, too. I would like to study more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue and workaround:

I think that in your situation, your goal is difficult to be directly achieved using your showing script. The reason for this has already been mentioned in [Gustavo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72387483/how-to-make-the-links-and-submission-function-work-in-a-web-form-that-is-created#comment127889929_72387483).

When I saw [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72387483/how-to-make-the-links-and-submission-function-work-in-a-web-form-that-is-created#comment127890902_72387483), it seems that you are required to run the Web Apps on the Google side.

In this case, I thought that a workaround might be required to be used. In this answer, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose a workaround. The point of this workaround is as follows.

- In your script, the value of `<select id="dropdownList" name="cake" class="form-control"></select>` is sent to `doPost` using `action="<?!= getScriptUrl(); ?>" method="post"` of the form.
- In this workaround, the value is sent to Google Apps Script using `google.script.run`. And, after the value was completely submitted, the HTML body is overwritten by `result.html`.

When this point is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### `index.html`

Please modify `index.html` as follows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!-- <?!= include("css"); ?> -->
  </head>
  <body id="body" onload="addOptions()">
    <form id="form">
      <div>
        <h1 id="Question">
          Choose either cheesecake or chocolate cake.
        </h1>
          <select id="dropdownList" name="cake" class="form-control"> 
          </select>
      </div>
      <p>
        <div style="width:100px;height:500px;border:1px solid #000;">
          Blank box to scroll down
        </div>
      </p>
      <p>
        Please do not forget what you've answered in the <a href="#Question" target="_self">question<a>
      </p>
      <div class="form-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" onclick="sample(this);return false;">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
  <?!= include('JavaScript') ?>
</html>
```

#### `JavaScript.html`

Please add the following function to `JavaScript.html`.

```js
function sample(e) {
  const f = document.getElementById("form");
  const obj = { parameters: [...f].reduce((o, g) => (o[g.name] = [g.value], o), {}) };
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler((res) => {
      document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = res;
    })
    .sample(obj);
}
```

- In this sample script, in order to directly use your `doPost`, the value of `obj` is prepared. Please be careful about this.

#### `Code.gs`: Google Apps Script side

Please add the following function to `Code.gs`. This function use your `doPost`.

```js
function sample(e) {
  return doPost(e).getContent();
}
```

### Testing:

When this modification is reflected in your script and your Web Apps is embedded to a Google site, when the submit button is clicked, the value of `cake` is sent to the Google Apps Script side and `result.html` is displayed. I thought that this situation might be your expected result.

### Note:

- This modification is a simple modification for explaining the workaround. So, please modify this for your actual situation.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- About the internal link of the Web Apps on Google site, it seems that when the while page of Web Apps is embedded and the scrollbar is not shown, the internal link doesn't work. When the scrollbar of the frame is shown, the link works. In this case, it seems that the internal link cannot be worked using both HTML and Javascript. And, I cannot confirm the error message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I confirmed that data submission and transition to `result.html` works by hitting the submit button. However, the internal link (`<a href="#Question" target="_self">question<a>` in the example) does not work. Do you have any idea how to enable internal links?

Comment: @Carlos Luis Rivera Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `However, the internal link (<a href="#Question" target="_self">question<a> in the example) does not work.`, when I tested it, the link worked. For example, now, when `height:500px` of `<div style="width:100px;height:500px;border:1px solid #000;">` is modified to `height:2000px` and test it again. When I tested it, I confirmed the link worked again. If this didn't work, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question.

Comment: @Carlos Luis Rivera By the way, when you modified the script, please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps just in case, and test it.

Comment: I did test your suggestion after I lengthened the box height and made a new deployment to enable the latest modification, but the link does not work, as you can see [here](https://sites.google.com/view/mwe4stackoverflow/). The link points https://n-j6gnyfpjwtxyzrrgdtkdpaoinmiz4ggwh7x74yy-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel#Question . I open the MWE site from Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, and Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: @Carlos Luis Rivera Thank you for replying. Now, I could replicate your new issue. It seems that when the while page of Web Apps is embedded and the scrollbar is not shown, the internal link doesn't work. When the scrollbar of the frame is shown, the link works. I could resolve your 1st question. But, I cannot resolve your 2nd question soon. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. I have to study more. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I cannot resolve your 2nd question soon and I think that my this answer might confuse other users.